Windows Registry context menu item not showing
I want to add a command to the context menu of .png files.
I opened the Registry Editor, went to Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pngfile\shell, added My Command\command under shell. It looks like this:

If I understand correctly, this should display an item called "My Command" upon right-clicking a .png file. But it doesn't - this is what I get:

No trace of "My Command".
I checked the extension/file association and it should be correct. If I go to Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.png, the (Default) string reads pngfile.
I have tried restarting Windows, still nothing.
What should I do to make it appear?

Note how, for example, 7-Zip adds itself to the context menu to all files and folders by setting up InprocServer32 with ID {23170F69-40C1-278A-1000-000100020000}. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/inprocserver32

Most likely, the .png/pngfile association has been over-ridden by Open with...  and the always use this... option. That creates an entry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts. Delete the .png subkey there and your command shhould appear...
